# Spotlight Search UserActivity is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I am getting crash logs from Crashlytics for Spotlight Search which is implemented by using CoreSpotlight framework and UserActivity. I am not able find reason behind crash. Please help [image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by calling activity in Main thread.